# How to upgrade kernel with all dependencies in Debian?

Tags: debian, linux-kernel

I tried to select a newer version in aptitude for `linux-image-amd64`, but it did not upgrade other packages like `linux-headers-amd64` which would likely result in broken system. I must be doing something wrong.

I could install more packages but I worry about modules, drivers, dkms, linux-tools and other things that might break and I'm not an expert do tell if the following does what I need.

```
# apt-get install -t jessie-backports \
linux-image-amd64 linux-headers-amd64 linux-tools \
--install-suggests
```

Is there a 'simple' process that would allow be to upgrade every package that depends on my current kernel version?

Answer (score 0):

To list dependencies:

```
$ apt-cache show linux-image-amd64
```

And then you can list their dependencies, etc.. You'll find it already is doing what you want. It has rules in there like here:

```
$ apt-cache show linux-image-3.2.0-4-amd64
...
Depends: kmod | module-init-tools, linux-base (>= 3~), initramfs-tools (>= 0.99~) | linux-initramfs-tool
```

So if your linux-base was older than version 3, or initramfs tools, etc. then it would require those to be updated too.

And if it's not doing what you want, then that's just a bug in how they set up the depends, and you won't find it using apt-cache. And hopefully that would be very rare (but some people said it happened with systemd on fedora depending on a newer kernel than what was installed).